# Django blog administration

Tags: python, django

I've managed to make a simple blog app in django using some tutorials, however there's one thing I'd like to change: when viewing all posts using admin panel, all of them are named **Post object**. Is there a way to fix it so there's a title of a post instead of Post object?

[image: Admin panel]

Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(u'Date of publishing')
    content = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to implement a `__unicode__` method on your model.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(u'Date of publishing')
    content = models.TextField(max_length=10000)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Note that in case you're using Python 3, you should use `__str__` instead.

Docs on this: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that it's \_\_str\_\_ instead of \_\_unicode\_\_ in Python 3, according to the documentation you link to.

Comment: Feel foolish because I've been using __unicode__ instead of __str__ :)
Thanks a lot!